# Agregar digitos a un jlabel con teclado

Tags: java, java-swing, keypressevent, jlabel

Estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora en Java, y lo mas común en proyectos academicos es que al dar clic en el numero de la pantalla se ponga el numero presionado en el JLabel asignado con los eventos del mouse; en este caso lo que intento hacer es llenar el jlabel pero con eventos de teclado pero no he podido saber como se hace.
Si alguien sabe se lo agradeceria...
Lo que intenté hacer fue lo siguiente:

```
private void panelNumerosKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1) {
        txtNumeros.setText("1");
    }
}
```

hace referencia al panel donde está el teclado numérico, también lo he intentado poner en el botón del numero tal como lo muestro a continuación:

```
private void btnUnoKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1) {
        txtNumeros.setText("1");
    }
}
```

pero lo que ocasiona es que me toque dar clic en el botón con el numero uno y ahí si luego me detecta el teclado 1 y pues esa no es la idea.
El diseño de la calculadora es asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

txtNumeros es el jLabel que tiene el numero 0.

Comment: Hola oarodriguez95, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y agregues la etiqueta correspondiente al lenguaje utilizado, además muestra que has intentado (sino la cerrarán), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score -1):

Vamos por partes, primero tengo que crear un escuchador de eventos de teclado (keyListener), lo agrego en el constructor de la clase que hereda de **JFrame** así:

```
addKeyListener( new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void keyPressed( java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt ) {
        pressed( evt );
     }
        // este no lo usamos, pero hay que agregarlo igual
     @Override
     public void keyReleased( java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt ) {
        
     }
  });
  setFocusable( true );  // necesario para que el frame pueda obtener el foco
```

Luego creo el método correspondiente, en el cuerpo de la clase:

```
void pressed( KeyEvent evt ) {
    int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();   
       // si usas el teclado numérico, 
    txtNumeros.setText( keyCode - 96 ); // los códigos van del "96" al "105"
       // sino, se complica, tienes que usar "if" porque códigos de los números van al 
       // revés, osea, el "0" tiene el código "48", el "1" el "47", etc, quedaría algp así:  
    if( keyCode == 48 ) {
        txtNumeros.setText( "0" );
    } 
    else if( keyCode == 47 ) {
        txtNumeros.setText( "1" );
    }
    else if( keyCode == 46 ) {
        txtNumeros.setText( "2" );
    }  // etc.
}
```

Te dejo un método que no usarás en este código pero puede servir más adelante.

```
    int key = evt.getModifiersEx();
```

Esto detecta las teclas "shift", "alt", etc.